# How do I get R to recognise a "time" column within a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I created a data frame, DF.

```
time <- c("10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00")

temperature <- c("15", "16", "17", "18", "18", "19")

DF <- data.frame(time, temperature)
```

Currently R recognises the “time” column as a list of characters. I want R to recognise the column as a time column.

I used the following code;

```
DF$time <- hms(DF$time)
```

But it does not give me the results I need.

How do I get it to recognise the “time” column as a list of times?

Comment: what results do you need/expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using package `hms`

```
time <- c("10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00")
temperature <- c("15", "16", "17", "18", "18", "19")

# make sure time columns is a character, not a factor
DF <- data.frame(time, temperature, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(hms)
DF$time <- as.hms(DF$time)

str(DF)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time       : 'hms' num  10:00:00 11:00:00 12:00:00 13:00:00 ...
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
 $ temperature: chr  "15" "16" "17" "18" ...
```